# Capture Fn key on microsoft keyboard wireless 850

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I am trying to capture or change the function of the Fn key on a microsoft keyboard wireless 850

My end goal is to redefine it with autohotkeys.

It seems that the Fn key is not detected and does not have a scan code.

Any help ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. The Fn key does not have a vk, it's managed by the keyboard itself to determine what vk to send when the second key is pressed. You could open then AHK keypress logs to check

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm SC and VK